# grails is unable to download jar from maven repo

Tags: maven-2, grails, build, dependencies, centos

I'm trying to do grails clean on my grails project on centoOS server ... It starts downloading dependencies but gets stuck on a particular jar, if I try downloading the jar directly from the browser it working but hangs when I do grails clean

```
[root]# /root/grails-1.3.4/bin/grails clean
Welcome to Grails 1.3.4 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /root/grails-1.3.4

Base Directory: /root/cooldealsnew
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1435ms.
Running script /root/grails-1.3.4/scripts/Clean.groovy
Environment set to development
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are in a network environment requiring a proxy to access external resources

you can add proxy configurations being used by Grails commands using **add-proxy**

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/add-proxy.html

Comment: its just this jar  all other jar are downloading from maven repo .... and I'm doing this on my CentOS server so no browsers.